# Vue.config.js not being respected

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am attempting to enable https from my vue.config.js file

- Vue.js version: 2.6.14
- @vue-cli version: 4.5.13

Current vue.config.js

```
module.export = {
    devServer: {
        /*
        Attempting to use certficate to utilize https, but neither approach works
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../certs/[key].pem')),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../certs/[cert].pem'))
        }*/
        https: true,
        public: 'https://localhost:8080/'
    },
}
```

I have even tried changing the port in the config file, but have had no luck. Part of me is thinking that the config file is not being read in properly, but I cannot understand why.

To start the dev server I currently use `npm run serve`

Current project directory structure

```
/project
 - /certs
 - /frontend
  -- /node_modules
  -- /public
  -- /src
  -- /tests
  -- babel.config.js
  -- jest.config.js
  -- package.json
  -- package-lock.json
  -- vue.config.js
```

package.json Scripts Section

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  }
```

Any pointers to what is going wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your `package.json` scripts section.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Updated my question with the scripts section

Comment: How exactly do you expect it to behave? https key is overwritten, no certs are used. If you wanted to set port you needed to set port key, not public. In case you suspect that a config is not read, you can always make syntax mistake or throw there and see what happens.

Comment: @EstusFlask When there is a syntax error I see an error thrown in command line, so I do know that the file is being read at the very least.  I have tried setting the port (with the port parameter), but when starting it starts with 8080 (even without 'public' defined. 

Currently I just want the development server to start in https (if i can get it to start with certs that would be great) . Certs are commented out since I was trying to get basic https to turn on.